# On the matrix norm inequality $\|A B\| \ge \|A\|\cdot \|B\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-norms

I know that $\|A B\| \le \|A\|\cdot \|B\|$. Are there any inequalities like the form: $\|A B\| \ge c \,\|A\|\cdot \|B\|$?

Comment: No, because $AB$ can be $0$ without $A$ or $B$ being $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you! If we can add some restrictions, such as symmetric matrix or something else, are there any inequalities as ‖‖≥‖‖⋅‖‖ ?

Comment: Symmetric won't be enough: $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=0$. And replace the zeros on the diagonals by $\varepsilon$ and you have regular, symmetric matrices with a (Frobenius) norm $>1$, while the product has an arbitrarily small norm.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks. That helps a lot.